# symfony 5 new Authenticator-based Security - createHasher() must be of the type array, object given

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I try to migrate my symfony old application to the newest authentication system using a custom hasher.

I'm facing with the following issue

> Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\PasswordHasherFactory::createHasher() must be of the type array, object given, called in /var/apache/www/celian_sf/vendor/symfony/password-hasher/Hasher/PasswordHasherFactory.php on line 112

The error occurs when form login is submitted and ´ authenticate method when returning passport object

Executing `bin/console security:hash-password` throws exactly same error

Using the standard algorithm `auto` for the hasher config the error goes away but I entered into an infinite loop too many redirect

To verify encoded password I need to get and user instance to retrieve the salt which always different.

**I know SHA1 is not strong enough that's no the point this is a legacy application**

Why this error occurs? What’s wrong with my implementation?

What's currently working:

```php
return new Passport(
      new UserBadge($login),
      new PasswordCredentials(
        
        function ($credentials, UserInterface $user) {
          return sha1($credentials . '||' . $user->getSalt()) === $user->getPassword();
        },
        $passw
      )
    );
```

I would like to hash password into my custom hasher.

security.yaml

```yaml
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true

    providers:
        # nom du provider
        myprovider:
            # type de provider
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Utilisateur
                property: loginUtil

    password_hashers:
        App\Entity\Utilisateur:
            id: App\Security\ShaOneEncoder
    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: false
            provider: myprovider
         
            user_checker: App\Security\UserChecker
        
            access_denied_handler: App\Security\AccessDeniedHandler
            
            custom_authenticators:
                - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: logout
```

LoginFormAuthenticator.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\PassportInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{

  private $params;

  public function __construct(ParameterBagInterface $params)
  {
    $this->params = $params;
  }

  /**
   * supports() - is called on every request
   *
   * @param Request $request
   * @return bool
   */
  public function supports(Request $request): bool
  {
    if (
        ($request->attributes->get('_route') === 'login_' . $request->getLocale()
          && $request->isMethod('POST'))
    ) {
        return true;
    }
  
    return false;
  }

  public function authenticate(Request $request): PassportInterface
  {
    // By default credentials are those of visiteur's account
    $login = $this->params->get('standard.login_visiteur');
    $passw = $this->params->get('standard.passwd_visiteur');

    // If user submitted form, get credentials from user's inputs
    if ($request->attributes->get('_route') === 'login_' . $request->getLocale() && $request->isMethod('POST')) {
      $login = $request->request->get('login');
      $passw = $request->request->get('passw');
    }

    return new Passport(new UserBadge($login), new PasswordCredentials($passw));
  }

  /**
   * Perform operations when authentication is success
   *
   * @param Request $request
   * @param TokenInterface $token
   * @param string $providerKey le nom du firewall derriere lequel l'utilisateur est authentifie
   * @return void
   */
  public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
  {
    // success
  }

  /**
   * Perform operations when authentication is failure
   *
   * @param Request $request
   * @param AuthenticationException $exception
   * @return void
   */
  public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception): Response
  {
    // failure
  }

  protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
  {
    // TODO: Implement getLoginUrl() method.
    return $this->urlGenerator->generate('login_fr');
  }
}
```

ShaOneEncoder.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class ShaOneEncoder implements UserPasswordHasherInterface
{
    private $params;

    private $em;
    
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, ParameterBagInterface $params)
    {
      error_log(__METHOD__);
      $this->params = $params;
      $this->em = $em;
    }
    /**
     * Encodes the raw password.
     *
     * @param string      $raw  The password to encode
     * @param string|null $salt The salt
     *
     * @return string The encoded password
     *
     * @throws BadCredentialsException   If the raw password is invalid, e.g. excessively long
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException If the salt is invalid
     */
    public function encodePassword($raw, $salt)
    {
      error_log(__METHOD__);
        return sha1($this->mergePasswordAndSalt($raw, $salt));
    }
    /**
     * Checks a raw password against an encoded password.
     *
     * @param string      $encoded An encoded password
     * @param string      $raw     A raw password
     * @param string|null $salt    The salt
     *
     * @return bool true if the password is valid, false otherwise
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException If the salt is invalid
     */
    public function isPasswordValid(UserInterface $user, $raw)
    {
      error_log(__METHOD__);
        $encodedCredentials = $this->encodePassword($raw, $salt);

        if ($encodedCredentials === $encoded) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

    /**
     * Merges a password and a salt.
     *
     * @param string $password the password to be used
     * @param string $salt     the salt to be used
     *
     * @return string a merged password and salt
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    protected function mergePasswordAndSalt($password, $salt)
    {
      error_log(__METHOD__);
        $passwd_separator = $this->params->get('standard.passwd_separator');
        
        return $password . $passwd_separator . $salt;
    }

    public function needsRehash(UserInterface $user): bool
    {
      error_log(__METHOD__);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Hashes a plain password.
     *
     * @throws InvalidPasswordException When the plain password is invalid, e.g. excessively long
     */
    public function hash(string $plainPassword): string
    {
      // should get the user to retrieve his salt then
      // return $this->encodePassword($plainPassword, $salt)
      die(__METHOD__);
    }

    /**
     * Verifies a plain password against a hash.
     */
    public function verify(string $hashedPassword, string $plainPassword): bool
    {
      die(__METHOD__); // Not executed except when using PasswordHasherInterface
      return $hashedPassword === $this->hash($plainPassword);
    }
}
```

If I use `PasswordHasherInterface` script execute verify method but not when using `UserPasswordHasherInterface`

Comment: And what's your question about this? What have you tried to resolve the given error?

Comment: My question is what’s wrong with my code ? I tried a lot of things too much to be all write here 

Comment: When exactly does the error appear?  Does bin/console security:hash-password work as expected or do you get the same error?  What happens if you use the standard algorithm: auto for your hasher config?

Comment: Your custom hasher should in fact implement only the PasswordHasherInterface.  The user stuff is handled by the security system.  Dealing with the user is part of what the PasswordHasherFactory does.  It's a bit mind numbing.  The error message seems to be coming from the fact that you pass a UserPasswordHasherInterface instead of a PasswordHasherInterface to the factory.

Comment: Point is using PasswordHasherInterface don’t allow me to retrieve user’s salt in order to hash password correctly.

Comment: Now I understand.  Have your hasher implement LegacyPasswordHasherInterface.  While I have not tested it for real, the salt should be passed.

Comment: Ho sounds good I didn’t see anything about that into symfony cookbook maybe I missed something up I’ll try it out

Comment: I just happened to see the interface in the vendor directory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thx to @Cerad solution is to use `Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\LegacyPasswordHasherInterface` that

> Provides password hashing and verification capabilities for "legacy" hashers that require external salts.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.3/src/Symfony/Component/PasswordHasher/LegacyPasswordHasherInterface.php

Comment: If you have not already, you might also want your User entity to implement the LegacyPasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface.  That should ensure the getSalt method will be available even after upgrading to 6.0 and beyond.

Comment: I'haven't but now yes many thanks to you @Cerad